# Can a DataGridViewRow be created in a function, independently of a control, and then added to an aribtrary control by the calling procedure?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Can a DataGridViewRow be created in a function, independently of a control, and then added to an arbitrary control by the calling procedure? Or must the row be created in association with a control, and then manipulated as needed?

I'm creating a VB.Net form with multiple DataGridView controls. They all have a similar purpose, with identical numbers & names of columns. I would like to create the rows & cells independently in a function, and then add them to the correct control after the function returns.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. This does not work. I receive the error `'New' cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'`, but I cannot find the solution.

```
Private Sub frmDataGridViewCellTest_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("colA", "A")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("colB", "B")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("colC", "C")
    Dim r As DataGridViewRow = CreateRow()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(r)
End Sub

Private Function CreateRow() As DataGridViewRow
    Dim r As New DataGridViewRow 'Create a new row independently of any DataGridView control.
    Dim i As Integer
    i = r.Cells.Add(New DataGridViewCell) 'error here
    r.Cells.Item(i).Value = "Hello"
    i = r.Cells.Add(New DataGridViewCell) '...and here
    r.Cells.Item(i).Value = "world"
    i = r.Cells.Add(New DataGridViewCell) '...and here
    r.Cells.Item(i).Value = "!"
    Return r
End Function
```

Comment: You're probably better off manipulating the `.DataSource` of the various `DataGridView` controls. For example, if each DataGridView has a `DataTable` as the data source, add the data to the DataTable, as appropriate, and the DataGridView will do all work for you to refresh the data that is displayed.

Comment: In this instance the columns & rows are being created programmatically, with additional bells & whistles such as colors & context menus. Or it will be...I haven't gotten that far yet. Still working out the background framework before I add the chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `DataGridViewRow`, you need also to initialize its [`DataGridViewCellCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellcollection?view=netframework-4.8) before you can add their values. The cells are created and initialized according to what type is defined in the [`DataGridViewColumn.CellTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate?view=netframework-4.8) property of each `DataGridViewColumn`. For this, create a new row then call the [`CreateCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.createcells?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.CreateCells);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which needs a `DataGridView` parameter to get the template of each cell as mentioned.

Wherefore, you can refactor the `CreateRow` function as follows:

```vb
Private Function CreateRow(dgv As DataGridView) As DataGridViewRow
    Dim row = New DataGridViewRow
    row.CreateCells(dgv, "Hello", "World", "!")
    Return row
End Function

' And maybe
Private Function CreateRow(dgv As DataGridView,
                            value1 As String,
                            value2 As String,
                            value3 As String) As DataGridViewRow
    Dim row = New DataGridViewRow
    row.CreateCells(dgv, value1, value2, value3)
    Return row
End Function
```

The caller:

```vb
Dim newRow = CreateRow(DataGridView1)
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow)

'Or
Dim newRow = CreateRow(DataGridView1, "Hello", "Word", "!")
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to pass the control to the function. I wasn't sure of that was a requirement. At some point I think I may have tried that, but then backtracked to see if I could trim it down and create the row independently of any control - and then I got lost. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A `DataGridView` doesn't contain vanilla `DataGridViewCell` objects. Each cell is a specific type that inherits `DataGridViewCell`. When you add a row via the grid itself, the cells are generated based on the columns, e.g. the cell generated for a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` will be a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`. That's the default column type so that's what your columns will be, so that's what you need to make your cells.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It's not like an Excel spreadsheet where it's an `Excel.Range` object that can be passed around. It also explains why newly created rows are tightly related to the parent DGV control. Thank you for your explanation.